# gitolite (version 3), update admin key

Tags: git, gitolite

I need to renew gitolite admin key. 
and followed this tutorial. [lost admin key/access](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html)

```
gitolite setup -pk alice.pub.
```

The command makes no error in my machine.

But, I can access the git repo list using old admin key yet.
and using the new key I just can access test repo only.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Did you try 3 paragraph from http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html?

Comment: I got confused. I just clone gitolite-admin using old admin-id, and remove old gitolite admin's id in the gitolite.conf file. And then add new admin id in there. And commit&push it. I works charm with new admin key. And old key doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can log on on the gitolite server, it is simpler to have a look at the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

You can see if your new key is published there with the `alice` name:

```
command="/path/to/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell alice",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAA...your_new_ssh_public_key
```

If not, as commented, the "[bypassing gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#bypass)" is a good way to fix locally (meaning directly from the gitolite server) the `gitolite.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks VonC. Your comments about git always helps me. :)